# sqlplus (Oracle XE) doesn't start on CentOS 7

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, linux, oracle-xe, centos

I followed the steps of this document: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18802/toc.htm#XEINL121, but sqlplus doesn't start. Even if I used the command: "sqlplus /nolog".
The other services start: APEX, Main page on: 127.0.0.1:8080, and It can connect with SYSTEM user in the page. However, sqlplus still doesn't start.
I executed the command: /etc/init.d/oracle-xe start, and shows a message with "OK".

When I check the status of the oracle-xe service, it shows: active (exited).

1. What does it mean "exited"? Why not "running"?
2. How can I execute sqlplus?

Comment: how do you start sqlplus? what is the exact error message?

Comment: The error message is something like: "bash: command not found".

Comment: This error message means that bash does not find the sqlplus program. You have to set up your environment appropriate. But that will not help to run Orace if Tomasz Klim is write.

Comment: I guess I've set up the environment variables, but It's still showing: "command not found".
However, I found how to start sqlplus using the GUI. Just writing: "SQL Command Line", It shows and starts sqlplus with no problem.

Comment: Problem solved for "command not found". I check again the environment variables, just a white space in the path.

Comment: Besides the PATH variable you have tset and export the ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables, too. Because you use the same Oracle installation as the database you should set the ORACLE_SID, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is only cannot start sqlplus, there are two alternatives:
1) If one has the GUI (GNOME or KDE), do the search: "sql command line", and It will appear Run SQL Command Line.
2) Check again the environment variables. Edit the files `/root/.bash_profile` and `/root/.bashrc` (for example: `# nano /root/.bash_profile`) and put the line (at the end): `./u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/oracle_env.sh`.

Answer (score 2):

This version of Oracle XE is based on 11g2 edition, which is not compatible with CentOS 7.

In fact, it isn't even 100% compatible with CentOS 6, however it will run there without problems, after you install a number of RPM packages not installed/required by Oracle installer (especially libaio both 32/64-bit).

These are formal OS requirements for XE 11g2:

- Oracle Linux, Red Hat Enterprise Linux, or CentOS - versions 4.7+ or 5.2+
- SUSE Linux Enterprise Server - versions 10 SP2 or 11

Comment: I installed the packages libaio, bc and flex: yum -y install libaio bc flex.

Comment: Still on CentOS 7? It won't work, since CentOS 7 uses systemd, while XE 11g2 is not compatible with systemd. I mentioned libaio for CentOS 6.

Comment: Sorry, It's working on CentOS 7. But the problem is finding the command "sqlplus" on Terminal.
I found how to start sqlplus using the GUI. Just writing: "SQL Command Line", It shows and starts sqlplus with no problem.